# Why does the Soft Keyboard appear?

Tags: android

I'm using the Android emulator to test my first Android application. While there is a functioning hard keyboard at the right side of the emulator window, the soft keyboard shows up when editing in an `EditText` control.

I'm aware of the option to hide the soft keyboard by using an instance of `InputMethodManager`, however I'm wondering why the soft keyboard does appear at all (when the hard keyboard is available).

To me, as a user, the soft keyboard in this case is rather distracting, hence I'd like to get rid of it if useful. - This question is about the practical context (i.e., is there any use of the soft keyboard when there is a hard keyboard, do real-world devices behave similarly to the emulator) and about general strategies to address the issue.

Thanks. I'll be upvoting any helpful hints.

Answer (score 1):

On my G1, when the hard keyboard was opened, the soft keyboard didn't appear. But I'm not sure whether a device which ALWAYS has a keyboard opened (like the Samsung Galaxy PRO if I'm not mistaken) does the same.

Since the emulator doesn't have a slide keyboard, I think that's the case for this behavior.

Comment: Do you think the emulator emulates a hard keyboard being available (which shows up at the right side of the emulator screen) and the case that it is not available (like in the "screen" area where the soft keyboard appears) - at the same time?

Comment: I don't know. I'd have to see how said Galaxy Pro handles the situation, but I think the emulator, not knowing the concept of 'sliding' the keyboard, presents you both so you get to choose which one to use. It would be interesting, though, having the possibility to choose by simulating a keyboard slide. I think the emulator developers are the ones to address this issue to.

Answer (score 1):

With a touch screen device + hard keyboard you have the flexibility to use both. On most devices with hard keyboards the keyboard has to be dragged out. It's much easier to just tap the screen. If you want to type a lot you would take the trouble to slide the keyboard out.

Android gives you the flexibility to program for all these behaviors.

Comment: Is there a way to emulate a hard keyboard that is available (thus the soft keyboard would not show up)? - Currently the emulator appears to be reflecting two states at once - the hard keyboard being available, and *not* being available, at the same time.

Comment: During SDK creation there are flags for 'Keyboard support' and 'Keyboard lid support' but I don't know whether they reflect the kind of behavior you want. This inconsistency exists because Android did not start out as a touch screen OS and the keyboard has been left as it is. Someone from the Android team would be better positioned to tell us more.

Comment: Unfortunately, "Keyboard support" set to "yes" and "Keyboard lid support" set to "no", the soft keyboard still shows up.

Comment: I guess we can only wait for this to be updated. Would be cool to test with a slide out keyboard. Found this link today: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/common-android-virtual-device-configurations/. Nothing much about the keyboard behavior on the AVD.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the AVD emulator *does* have a slide-out keyboard.
The AVD option "Keyboard support" indicates whether the emulated device has *any* form of physical keyboard. The option "Keyboard lid support" indicates whether the device has a keyboard that can be opened or closed (slid out or what have you).
As far as actually "opening" and "closing" the keyboard on a device set up with these options, 
you need to switch the orientation which is generally what you do with real-world slide-out-keyboard phones, e.g. the original Droid:

[Original Droid with slide-out keyboard open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxdm1.jpg)

In the emulator, you control this orientation change with `Ctrl+F11`/`Ctrl+F12` or `7`/`9` (on the number pad only, with `NumLk` off).
You can confirm the keyboard opening and closing states by checking the value `getResources().getConfiguration().hardKeyboardHidden == config.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES`

As far as whether the soft keyboard appears or not, it appears to me that handling such things is up to you as the programmer. Here's an example you can try in AVD:

- Set up an emulator with "Keyboard support" and "Keyboard lid support" both set to yes.
- Launch the emulator, then open Android's built in Messaging app.
- Click in one of the text boxes - the soft keyboard should show up.
- Switch the orientation of the emulator with Ctrl+F12 - the soft keyboard should now disappear

  - Note there seems to be a problem with the emulator itself, that switching back to portrait mode doesn't cause apps to redraw themselves back to portrait layout. but they will switch back to closed keyboard mode, which yields some odd, sideways-y behavior.

For an example of code to catch the keyboard opening/closing events, check out: http://www.how-to-develop-android-apps.com/how-to-detect-screen-orientation-change-in-android/

Comment: It might be on some phones that this design handled acoss the board in the UI the phone manufacturers designed. I'm curious to know how your app which keeps having the soft keyboard open behaves on your actual phone...

Comment: Actually, I've seen real devices fail to return to portrait mode after closing the slider keyboard, so this appears to be a system software issue and not an emulator-specific issue.

Comment: @mlepage I wasn't saying it was failing to go into portrait mode when the slider keyboard was closed, I was saying it fails to go into portrait mode when I... set it to portrait mode, I guess. I'm not doubting what you saw, but I wouldn't want people to rely on them being connected bugs (Especially because I was using, I think, the Gingerbread-era emulator at the time).

Answer (score 0):

After testing on real world devices; On the motorola milestone that has a sliding keyboard that if it's open the soft keyboard is not shown, but when it's closed the soft keyboard is shown. On the HTC Cha-Cha, that has a permanently shown keyboard, the phone always uses the hardware keyboard. Even when in landscape and the hard keyboard would be very difficult to use  it doesn't show a soft keyboard (Even after installing a soft keyboard I was unable to select it for use under Keyboard & Language Settings).

For additional information about the phone you can use the following.They will return the keyboard type and whether or not it is a hard keyboard and shown. Note: Phones without a hard keyboard that I've tested report that hardKeyboardHidden=2; (Which indicates hidden=yes), but type reports as soft keyboard which makes sense.

```
    Configuration config = getContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
    int keyboardHidden=config.hardKeyboardHidden;
    int keyboard=config.keyboard;
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO